# Is it possible to train a CNN for MNIST under 1 minute with CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, mnist

I am programming a CNN example for demonstration purposes to university students and it should classify MNIST with upwards of 80% accuracy. I use the following architecture and the training takes like 10 Minutes to reach that accuracy even if I use a relatively high batch size of 128. I am using the standard CPU on Google Colab without any hardware accelerator, the AdaDelta cost function, 10 epochs and  categorical cross entropy loss function.

Is it possible to improve the training time or is it impossible to reach 80% accuracy under 1 Minute with the given hardware?

```
    Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 13, 13, 32)       0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 11, 11, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 5, 5, 64)         0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 3, 3, 64)          36928     
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 576)               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 64)                36928     
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 10)                650       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 93,322
Trainable params: 93,322
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get very fast training with the following model:

```
model = Sequential()                                 

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(28,28,1))) 
convLayer01 = Activation('relu')                     
model.add(convLayer01)


model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))  
model.add(Activation('relu'))                       
convLayer02 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))          
model.add(convLayer02)

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3, 3)))    
convLayer03 = Activation('relu')                  
model.add(convLayer03)

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))          
model.add(Activation('relu'))                   
convLayer04 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))      
model.add(convLayer04)

model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
                
model.add(Dense(10))           
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

The trick in this case is to use `GlobalAveragePooling2D` instead of Dense layers. I got >90% accuracy in 1 epoch.